# Iterating on dictionary throws TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, iteration

I am trying to iterate over my `dictionary` with the following code:

```
num_detections = int(detection['num_detections'])
output_dict = {key:value[0, :num_detections].numpy() 
                for key,value in detection.items()}
```

But I get

> File "main.py", line 60, in 
>           for key,value in detection.items()}
>
> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

When I print out `detection` it's shaped like a dictionary and `print(type(detection))` gives me `<class 'dict'>`

Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is comma in list slicing. I think you wanted this:

```py
num_detections = int(detection['num_detections'])

output_dict = {key:value[0 :num_detections].numpy() 
                for key,value in detection.items()}
```